# Is it possible to use XBox controller with PoweredUp

Tags: powered-up, remote-control, 3rd-party

I have a couple of PoweredUp kits that I tweaked in the app but now, I would like to get more control on them using a physical remote.

I own an Xbox One Bluetooth controller and I thought I saw some people using them with Lego but I see nothing in the available blocks.

Did I miss something? Is it only available with Mindstorms 51515 or did I dreamt all that?

*Edit to distinguish from mentionned potential duplicate:*
Note that the root of the question is to find a way to use a compatible physical controller with PoweredUp hubs and not necessarily to find an alternative app though the use of a different app may be a solution.

Comment: I don't understand why the question was flag as a duplicate to a question that search for an alternative to Control+ when my question is about how to use a physical controller. Could a moderator please explain? Thank you.

Comment: It says I have to edit the question to highlight the difference between the associated question and mine but quite honestly, I can't see how I could achieve that since the actual question never mentions Control+ and explicitely mention it is about an XBox controller. I'll try something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And you can do that with a help of third party app called BrickController 2. Smartphone is required as a middle point connecting both hub and controller. There's a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=irMby1yHxYs) explaining how it works.

Supported platforms:

- Android 4.3+
- iOS 8+

Supported receivers:

- SBrick - both normal and plus (output only)
- BuWizz 1
- BuWizz 2
- BuWizz 3
- Lego PowerFunctions infrared receiver on Android devices having IR
  emitter
- Lego Powered-Up hub
- Lego Boost Hub
- Lego Technic Hub
- Lego WeDo 2.0 Smart Hub
- Circuit Cubes

Application sources:

- [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.scn.BrickController2)
- [iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/brickcontroller2/id1441923224?l=hu&ls=1)
- [GitHub](https://github.com/imurvai/brickcontroller2)

Comment: Does the job. Just sad it is not directly supported by Lego in PoweredUp so we could also use all the programming features available. Nice App though.